# Check if data/prop are passed or not?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I got a component that i pass in some data to. I want to check if "title" is passed or not, and conditionally set its value. As it works now, the value i pass just overrides. How would i do that?

```
<Meta title="test" />
```

Component

```
<template>
  <vue-headful
    :title="this.title"
  />
 </template>
 <script>
import vueHeadful from "vue-headful";

export default {
  name: "Meta",
  components: { vueHeadful },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "default val"
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Meta component you are not defining the prop, but a variable in data. You should delete the title from data and add a prop:

```
props: 
   {title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default val'
    }},
```

[See documentation on props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation)

You also do not need `this.` before `title` in your template.
`<vue-headful :title="title" />` will be enough.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried that. But the default gets returned from a json translations file. So it wont work. "this.$t("SITE_META_TITLE");" is what returns the default string.

Comment: Where does this `this.$t(...)` come from? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: If you want to use a translated string as input for your Meta component, you should bind it to the component: 
<Meta :title="$t('SITE_META_TITLE')" />

Comment: `$t()` is most probably from `vue-i18n`. You can check if a given translation exists with [`$te()`](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#vue-injected-methods) and then conditionally render a default value. So you can create a computed property like
`get displayedTitle() { return this.$te(this.title) ? this.$t(this.title) : 'default val'; }`

Or such a trick will be necessary for a parent component if you resolve a translation there.